# python: when reading and saving a image the color change

Tags: python, image, scipy, python-imaging-library, opencv

I tried loading and saving  images with python using cv2,PIL, scipy , but the saved image has a bit different color compare to the original.

I am loading and saving tif format, so i expect no color change.

link to the image I am using:
https://data.csail.mit.edu/graphics/fivek/img/tiff16_c/a0486-jmac_MG_0791.tif

[the difference between loaded image and saved image is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eao53.jpg)

can you help me understand what I am doing wrong? why the color change?

update:
the problem is because the image is prophoto rgb color.
does anyone knows how can i convert a batch of images from prophoto rgb to rgb?

thanks,
yoav

option 1:

```
img = imread(file_name)
imsave('imread.tif', img)
```

option 2:

```
img = cv2.imread(file_name)
cv2.imwrite('cv2.tif', img)
```

option 3:

```
img = Image.open(file_name)
img.save('pil.tif')
```

Comment: Before saving, can you display the image on the screen and see if the colors change then.

Comment: FYI: You could also try using [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

Comment: same result with tifffile with the code: image = tiff.imread(file_path)
    tiff.imsave('tifffile.tif', image)

Comment: the color change when i display the image (no saving only loading). i used: plt.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest') plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

I *think* OpenCV is more interested in Computer Vision - i.e. detecting and measuring objects etc than printing or high quality image reproduction, editing and printing, so it pretty much ignores ICC profiles. If anyone knows better, I am happy to be corrected.

You can use **ImageMagick** to convert images from one format to another, and to do many, many other things, one of which is changing colour profiles. So, I think, if you go to [this website](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter) and download an sRGB profile (I chose the first one with *"preference"* in its name) and save it as `sRGB.icc`, you can change one of your ProPhoto images to a normal sRGB image with the following command in Terminal:

```
convert input.tif -profile sRGB.icc output.tiff
```

Try that and see if it works. If so, **make a copy of your images** and on a copy, you can run `mogrify` to do the whole lot in one go - beware and make a copy like I suggest because it will very quickly alter all your images...

```
magick mogrify -profile sRGB.icc *tif
```

You can see the embedded profile and loads of other information about an image using **ImageMagick**'s `identify` command:

```
magick identify -verbose OneOfYourImages.tiff
```